# How to style image in variable?

Tags: php, css, styles, ipb

I have an image being pulled out of a forum (avatars), but every time i grab them, they are not fitting my div, no matter what i do, i'm wondering how can i fit that image inside my div?

Here's the line i'm talking about:

```
<div id="image">'.$ipbwi->member->photo($friend['friends_friend_id']).'</div>
```

And here's a whole foreach:

```
<?php
$friends = $ipbwi->member->friendsList(false,true);
foreach($friends as $friend){
echo '
<div class="friend">
<div id="image">'.$ipbwi->member->photo($friend['friends_friend_id']).'</div>
<div class="username">'.$ipbwi->member->id2displayname($friend['friends_friend_id']).'</div>
</div>
';
}
?>
```

I'm using ipbwi to pull data from ipb forum and i would like to scale all the images to (example) 40x40px.

Edit:

here's the css i'm using for img on div: #friend #image img{width: 40px; height: 40px;}

Thanks in advance!

Comment: *The PHP (and the variable) is irrelevant.* Look at the HTML output. Is it valid/expected? And, if so, how can *the HTML* be styled with CSS? There should likely be an `<img>` tag since a profile picture is *data* and thus not suitable for CSS. The data is supplied to `<img>` via the `src` attribute - either to a resource or with a Data URI.

Comment: I agree with @user2246674. If you show us the output html and CSS that you are using, we could perhaps be of some assistance.

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16352774/is-it-possible-to-render-an-image-in-two-sizes-with-correct-proportion/16352853#16352853

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding the style rule

```
.friend img { max-width:100px; max-height:100px }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done this in the past.

```
.img-resize {
  width: 200px;
  height : auto;
}

.img-resize {
  width: auto;
  height : 300px;
}
```

Create a css class `img-resize` and give it the width and height you desire. This will keep the aspect ration. Use like: `<img src="http://example.com/12.jpg"  class="img-resize" />`
Then you can just replace the `scr` with value from the db.

Answer (score 0):

Use this CSS to resize your images:

```
img {
  max-width: 40px;
  max-height: 40px;
}
```

Also, keep in mind that this will aplly to every `img` tag on your page, so to be more specific you could do something like:

```
.friend img {
  max-width: 40px;
  max-height: 40px;
}
```

This will only re-size images that are inside of a `div` tag with the `class` "friend"